# MySQL won't open

Tags: mysql, database, windows-xp, xampp

I tried to read some of this in [here](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=196692&sid=69a39020661c291f3519f3c1cb1ef295) and here [here](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=195455&sid=e9156e114245e1f3f308481b83ab731d) and it still doesn't work.

I also reinstalled xampp twice and restarted again and again to no avail.

Here's the mysql_error.log:

```
130128 23:52:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130128 23:52:08 [Warning] option 'innodb-buffer-pool-size': signed value 0 adjusted to 5242880
130128 23:52:08 [Warning] option 'innodb-additional-mem-pool-size': signed value 0 adjusted to 524288
130128 23:52:08 [Warning] option 'innodb-log-file-size': signed value 0 adjusted to 1048576
130128 23:52:08 [Warning] option 'innodb-log-buffer-size': signed value 0 adjusted to 262144
130128 23:52:08 [Warning] option 'innodb-lock-wait-timeout': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
130128 23:52:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130128 23:52:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130128 23:52:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130128 23:52:08 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 
runtime error R6002
- floating point support not loaded
130129  0:04:10 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130129  0:04:10 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130129  0:04:10 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130129  0:04:10 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130129  0:04:10 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 
runtime error R6002
- floating point support not loaded
```

Comment: It says it's starting crash recovery. Does it ever complete it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your MySQL DB crashed. Best solution is to restart your machine and restart XAMPP.